# How to display an image for a second when we click on a div?

Tags: jquery

I am using jquerymbiles 1.4.2.I want my image to be display for a 5 seconds when we click on a div.
The code which i am using in my page is here
   click

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
$(".hr").click(function(){
   $("#imgstate").show();
});
});
</script>
```

The above code displays the image when we click n a div but i dm not getting how to hide it after a 5 seconds please help me in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[.delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".hr").click(function () {
        $("#imgstate").show().delay(5000).hide();
    });
});
```

---

Try to use `.setTimeout()` here:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".hr").click(function () {
        $("#imgstate").show();
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#imgstate").hide();
        }, 5000);
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Y8LtK/)**

Comment: i tried that but its not working if i add $("#imgstate").show().delay(5000).hide(); its not showing even image

Comment: You can't use `delay` with `show ` and `hide` as they're not part of the animation queue.  This would work instead : `$("#imgstate").fadeIn(1).delay(5000).fadeOut(1);`